# Solution to upload image file via WCF service?

Tags: rest, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-web-api

Being surfing for last 3-4 days downloading, running and fixing issues with available demo projects online, none of them work so far.

I need to upload an image using WCF webservice. Where from client side end I like to upload it by means of form (multipart/form-data), including some file description.

Any solution working with proper answer? My mind is really stacked overflow trying different solution. One which I initially have I am able to upload a text file where file gets created with some extra content in it. I need to upload image file.

> ------------cH2ae0GI3KM7GI3Ij5ae0ei4Ij5Ij5 
>   
>  Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filename\"
>   
>   
>  testing file gets upload...

When I upload image file, the image file is empty.

Initial Code (one implantation), method by means of which I get the .txt file as above, in case of image its blank (or say corrupt don't know)

```
    private string uplaodFile(Stream stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        int length = sr.ReadToEnd().Length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
        FileStream f = new FileStream(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Upload"), "test.png"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        f.Close();
        stream.Close();
        return "Recieved the image on server";
    }
```

another;

```
public Stream FileUpload(string fileName, Stream stream)
        {
            string FilePath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Upload"), fileName);
            int length = 0;
            using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                int readCount;
                var buffer = new byte[8192];
                while ((readCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    length += readCount;
                }
            }

            return returnJson(new { resp_code = 302, resp_message = "occurred." });
        }
```

Comment: *Don't* use WCF for this. WCF means SOAP. Uploading a file isn't a job for a web service, it's a job for plain-old HTTP POST. What you ask is no different than any file upload form.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer. Please show code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not necessarily, the WebHttpBinding supports RESTful services, but it's certainly not the easiest way of doing REST in .NET

Comment: @TomW there are lots of code already on the stackoverflow(on internet) I have tried already, I want some proper working solution with details. If you could help.

Comment: @smkrn110 post **your** code. There's no way anyone can help if you won't specify what causes the problem.

Comment: @TomW have update the question with the code. Some other (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797979/Uploading-Downloading-a-file-using-WCF-REST-servic)

Comment: You're creating an empty file then writing its contents (nothing) to another file. Please post the code you are using to receive a file upload, so that's the WCF contract interface and the service implementation.

Comment: update the code, which was working apology for put random code as I was hit and try.

Comment: @TomW any hint what was wrong or if you have any better solution?

Comment: You're trying to read the incoming stream twice - once with `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` and again with `stream.Read`. You can't do that, (network) streams are not replayable. Instead initialise a fixed length buffer and read from the incoming stream.and write to the file stream in a loop, there are innumerable examples of this on the web

Comment: @TomW Kindly rectify the issue place another; its given me the same result blank image file.

Comment: Your new code snippet looks fine to me. If you debug into it, can you see the loop being executed and bytes being written?

Comment: Its not working as told, already I tried different approaches even verify web.config according with each approaches.

Comment: Hey @TomW Issue is fixed, actually I did not focus what I have posted, as I removed the above text content disposition .... the image gets recover, thanks so far being responsive.